# FLUTTER: how to do yahoo oauth2 login?

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I have searched many websites and used many examples. But nothing seems working. I need Flutter oauth2 Yahoo login code or SDK

Comment: I think it is possible with Firebase auth.

Comment: Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/yahoo-oauth

Comment: @rstrelba its for Android SDK not for Flutter